# DailyRollingFileAppender configuration

Tags: grails, log4j

I am using the following configuration to create log files but the log.info messages in grails service and println messages from controller are not getting saved in the log file:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name:"file", fileName:"logFile.log",
                datePattern: '\'_\'yyyy-MM-dd', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ISO8601}\t%p\t%c:%L\t%m%n'))
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ISO8601}\t%p\t%c:%L\t%m%n')
    }

    root {
        info 'stdout', 'file'
        error 'stdout', 'file'
        additivity = true
    }

    error  stdout:
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    info  stdout:
            'grails.app' , additivity: false
}
```

Comment: `println` messages will never get saved to the file, as for log messages I am guessing the `additivity:false` is preventing them from getting to the root logger.

Comment: @GregorPetrin I changed it to true but doesn't work. Also during deployment is says java.io.FileNotFoundException: logFile.log (Permission denied). Even though its permission is set to 777.